# Trying to wire new kitchen light

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, ceiling, light

I live in the U.K. and I’m trying to wire a new light fixture in my ceiling. Coming out of the ceiling I have two red wires twisted together three black wires of which two are twisted together and then two ground wires. On the new light fixture I have a slot for a neutral, a ground and a live. Oh yea and of course the light is controlled by a switch. I just can’t seem to figure out how to attach the wires to the fixture. Please help.

Comment: Are you saying that the original light is no longer connected, so you have no reference? My hunch is that there's another red (or yellow) wire which you haven't mentioned. Typically there are at least as many hots as neutrals. A photo would be great.

Comment: We need pictures. The new fixture sounds non-standard. UK ceiling roses [should] have a very specific layout - [almost] foolproof.

Comment: Nope there’s only the wires I spoke of coming out of the hole in the ceiling. Sorry I’m not there right now or I’d send a picture. The light I’m trying to put up is brand new bought from B&Q.